# Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints. asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to get start date and end date from two text box and according to that date's I have to fetch data from db and display into a grid view.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    String str = DateTime.Now.ToString(TextBox1.Text);
    DateTime tm = Convert.ToDateTime(str);
    String str2 = DateTime.Now.ToString(TextBox2.Text);
    DateTime tm2 = Convert.ToDateTime(str2);

    solarDataSet2TableAdapters.tbl_energy_reportTableAdapter state;
    state = new solarDataSet2TableAdapters.tbl_energy_reportTableAdapter();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
    dt = state.GetGridDataBy(DropDownList1.SelectedValue,DropDownList2.SelectedValue,  

    str, str2);  // Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values  
    //violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints. asp.net c#  

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You have to debug to find the actual reason for the error(s). Set a breakpoint at `dt = state.GetGridDataBy...`. Execute this line in the debugger's  [quick-watch-window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx). After that execute [`dt.GetErrors()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.geterrors(v=vs.110).aspx) in the quick-watch-window and look at each row's [`RowError`-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowerror(v=vs.110).aspx). There you'll find it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : I have done the above step. Put a break point on dt and run the quick watch window.data set visualizer doesn't shows table. And where should I apply the dt.GetErrors() method?

Comment: I don't know what i could add to my above comment to make it more clear. What don't you understand? Execute `dt=state.GetGridDataBy(DropDownList1.SelectedValue,DropDownList2.SelectedValue, str, str2);` in the debugger. You'll see the constraint-exception then in the debugger window. Then execute `dt.GetErrors()` also in the quick-watch dialog. As a result you'll get all rows which have errors. You'll find the  meaningful error-messages in every row's `RowError` property (also in the quick-watch dialog of the debugger). Is it clear now?

Comment: So have you got it to work? What was the real problem?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Actually the issue is related with data set. Any way thank you for your kind co operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps given below:

This actually worked for me, hope even you able to clear.

1. Go to the dataset and copy the query of `GetGridDataBy`.
2. Now go back to the main dataset window and delete the `GetGridDataBy` query from the list.
3. Now ADD new query and paste the query details which you have copied from the previous `GetGridDataBy` query.
4. And now name it something else like `GetGridDataBy2`
5. Replace all the `GetGridDataBy` from the code behind with `GetGridDataBy2`.
6. And then Run.

Sometimes this error occurs due to malfunction under auto-generation of signature code. This steps will help you resolve this issue. All the best!